# Powershell List Serial Ports + description

Tags: list, powershell, serial-port

I'd like to create a list of COM port on my computer (COM port + description). My point is to create a COM port list in order to communicate with a switch using an USB/RS232 converter.

What I try so far :

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort | Select-Object DeviceID,Description
```

But all the COM port does not appear
(example: COM11 is missing)

another attempt :

```
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
```

here the port I need is present but the description is missing.
(example : COM11 is present but with no details)

Comment: This question is not written in English.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
$c1 = new-object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort com1
$c1
BaseStream             :
BaudRate               : 9600
BreakState             :
BytesToWrite           :
BytesToRead            :
CDHolding              :
CtsHolding             :
DataBits               : 8
DiscardNull            : False
DsrHolding             :
DtrEnable              : False
Encoding               : System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
Handshake              : None
IsOpen                 : False
NewLine                :

Parity                 : None
ParityReplace          : 63
PortName               : com1
ReadBufferSize         : 4096
ReadTimeout            : -1
ReceivedBytesThreshold : 1
RtsEnable              : False
StopBits               : One
WriteBufferSize        : 2048
WriteTimeout           : -1
Site                   :
Container              :
```

You could do this for each port that comes back from getportnames(). You'll probably want to call the Dispose() method on each port and set $c1 to $null after you finish gathering info for it.

Comment: For the sake of completion for a newbie who doesn't understand how to put it all together, here is my combo:

`$COMportList = [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()`

`ForEach ($COMport in $COMportList)`

`{`

`$temp = new-object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $COMport`

`echo $temp.PortName`

`echo $temp.BaudRate`

`$temp.Dispose()`

`}`

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work any longer for PowerShell 5.1.19041.906. @Mark Stouffer's answer works.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers seem to be for deprecated Powershell objects.

I was able to use this:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_SerialPort | Select-Object Name, Description, DeviceID
```

Remove `| Select-Object Name, Description, DevideID` to inspect additional properties.

Answer (score 3):

did this:

https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+get+available+com+ports&gws_rd=ssl

found this:

http://empegbbs.com/ubbthreads.php/topics/362862/Windows_command_to_quickly_lis

which led to this:

https://github.com/todbot/usbSearch/blob/master/listComPorts.vbs

so i adapted it to this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity -Filter "Name LIKE 'com%'" | Where Name -match 'COM\d+'
```

or this

```
Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT Name, Description from Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Name LIKE "com%"'
```

Comment: This no longer works in PowerShell 5.1.19041.906.
@mark stoffer's answer does work.

Comment: thanks for letting us know, and thanks to @mark for the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanna see all the good details, you should cook up something like the following:

```
    $mydevs = (Get-PnPDevice | Where-Object{$_.PNPClass -in  "WPD","AndroidUsbDeviceClass","Modem","Ports" } | 
        Where-Object{$_.Present -in "True"} | 
        Select-Object Name,Description,Manufacturer,PNPClass,Service,Present,Status,DeviceID | 
        Sort-Object Name)


    $mydevs | Format-Table Description, Manufacturer, PNPClass, Service,
        @{Label="COM port"; Expression={ ($_.Name -Match "\((COM\d{1,2})\)" | Out-Null && $Matches[1]) }},
        @{Label="VID:PID"; Expression={ ($_.DeviceID -Match "USB\\VID_([0-9a-fA-F]{4})\&PID_([0-9a-fA-F]{4})" | Out-Null && ('{0}{1}{2}' -f ${Matches}[1], ":", ${Matches}[2]).ToLower() ) }},
        Present, Status
```

The output is:

```
Description                                 Manufacturer         PNPClass Service   COM port VID:PID   Present Status
-----------                                 ------------         -------- -------   -------- -------   ------- ------
Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL Intel                Ports    Serial    COM7                  True OK
USB Serial Device                           Microsoft            Ports    usbser    COM4     8087:0aca    True OK
USB Serial Device                           Microsoft            Ports    usbser    COM6     8087:0aca    True OK
```

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76250070/1147688).